# SQL to return list of years since a specific year

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need a list of years as a recordset starting with 2004 to current year (in desc order), **without writing a stored procedure**. Is this possible? (SQL Server 2005). So it should return:

2009
2008
2007
2006
2005
2004

Comment: I suppose creating temporary tables or UDF's is off limits as well?

Comment: While an interesting puzzle, I'm suspicious of the reason behind needing this.  And while Lieven's solution will work, it is highly dependent on the table having enough rows.  It creates a bad dependency.

Comment: @Will, you make a valid point about the reason why one would be needing this. I'm not sure about the dependency problem. The statement will more than likely get used in a larger statement. If a table from this larger statement gets used, I would be ok with that dependency.

Comment: The requirement is simply to populate a parameter drop-down on a SQL Report to allow selection of any year since 2004.

Comment: @Graeme. In that case, Will has a point about creating a bad dependency. To minimize the impact, I'd choose a system table that holds enough rows and isn't likely going to change.

Comment: Can you consider marking Joshua's answer as the accepted answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5677924/39532

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This gets all years from 2004 to the present, using a recursive CTE:

```
with yearlist as 
(
    select 2004 as year
    union all
    select yl.year + 1 as year
    from yearlist yl
    where yl.year + 1 <= YEAR(GetDate())
)

select year from yearlist order by year desc;
```

Comment: I tend to reserve downvoting for those answers that are plain wrong, not for answers I simply don't like. A very subjective area, I know but I don't feel the three of us deserved your downvote.

Comment: +1 btw for a solution I would recommend today (but didn't grasp back then)

Comment: @Lieven, I only downvoted 2 answers, yours and DJ's (how did you even know that, anyway? Just guessing?). DJ's seems clearly wrong to me. It doesn't meet the basic requirements of the question. Yours works, but it seemed potentially dangerous to me in that people searching for this question might use that solution without thinking about what happened if their table was too small, or was truncated, or something at a later time. It seems like a poor solution to rely on data that may change or be out of your control. A downvote may have been too harsh...not sure. But it seems I can't undo it now.

Comment: the risks you outline are correct but they are also mentioned in my answer. The guessing wasn't all that difficult. One other answer after 2 years, two downvotes, you posting a new comment about a wrong answer and posting a new (fwiw, better)answer... .

Comment: Now in 2014 - this is what I would use, so swapped the answer from Lieven to here..

Answer (score 6):

Updated to return current year plus previous 5 years. Should be very fast as this is a small recordset.

```
SELECT YEAR(GETDATE()) as YearNum
UNION
SELECT YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 as YearNum
UNION
SELECT YEAR(GETDATE()) - 2 as YearNum
UNION
SELECT YEAR(GETDATE()) - 3 as YearNum
UNION
SELECT YEAR(GETDATE()) - 4 as YearNum
UNION
SELECT YEAR(GETDATE()) - 5 as YearNum
ORDER BY YearNum DESC
```

Comment: -1 unions have bad performance & this doesn't cover "current year" without modifications to the query.

Comment: heh - missed the current year comment but the performance impact of something this small would be negligible

Comment: @DJ sorry, I totally misread the intended query, I for some reason thought this was going to be joined with an order table or something. My mistake. Your query is perfectly fine.

Comment: This query doesn't meet the requirements, because it would need to have another UNIONed select added every year.

Answer (score 5):

Using `ROW_NUMBER` on any column from any large enough (stable) table would be one way to do it.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT TOP 100 2003 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY <AnyColumn>) AS Yr
  FROM dbo.<AnyTable>
  ) Years
WHERE Yr <= YEAR(GETDATE())
```

*Note that `<AnyTable>` should contain at least the amount of rows equal to the amount of years you require.*

#### Edit (Cudo's to Joshua)

- Preferably, you'd select a table wich you know will not get truncated and/or deleted. A large enough `system table` should come to mind.
- At present, being a lot older and wiser (older at least), I would implement this requirement using a `CTE` like mentioned in the answer given by Joshua. The `CTE` technique is far superior and less error prone than current given `ROW_NUMBER` solution.

Comment: That works - presumably I should choose a table with only a handful of rows, or does it make no difference?

Comment: @Graeme, by doing a TOP 100 it will make little difference wich table you choose but I'd use a small one.

Comment: You have to create a table, add the current year - 2004 number of rows, then run this query? What happens next year?

Comment: @scotty2012. No table gets created. Next year gets included by the YEAR(GETDATE()) statement. The only thing fixed is the starting year. There are no 2004 rows, only 100 as specified in the TOP 100 clause. This query will work up until 2103

Comment: What happens when the table you're selecting from only has 2 rows in it?

Comment: Only two years will be returned.

Comment: So if only 2 rows would be returned, then this would not give the expected results.

Comment: @Eppz, I explained in my response that AnyTable should be replaced with a table with "at least" the amount of rows as the amount of years you're asking.

Comment: You need to add ORDER BY 1 desc to get the years in the correct order.

Comment: @Eppz. True, I left that as an excercise to the reader ;) (read as: I honestly forgot).

Comment: Downvoted because this may fail if a table shrinks, or is truncated, or if someone copies your code to a new system and does a metadata-only database restore so they can start with a blank slate, or...etc. Sure, it will *often* work, but this seems to me to be the sort of code that introduces obscure bugs when the system is used in a way that the programmer doesn't expect.

Comment: @Joshua, OP can use an system table. Little chance that would get truncated. For all the rest, I already agreed to that.

Comment: @Lieven - I'd argue that the possibility of a sufficiently big table later shrinking was never specifically addressed, and mentioning a danger in your comments isn't the same as mentioning it in your answer itself. But if you edit your answer so the dangers are more expressly stated it would improve your answer and I then can remove the downvote (After 1 hour the system won't let me unless the answer changes).

Comment: @Joshua - Point taken. I'll edit the answer because it will indeed make it better.

Comment: @Lieven - I've removed my downvote. There's still another one from someone else.

Comment: @Joshua - I believe it was already there. Someone in the past must have also disagreed. Turns out he was right.

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @YEARS TABLE (Y INT)
DECLARE @I INT, @NY INT
SELECT @I = 2004, @NY = YEAR(GETDATE())
WHILE @I <= @NY BEGIN
    INSERT @YEARS SELECT @I
    SET @I = @I + 1
END
SELECT Y 
FROM @YEARS
ORDER BY Y DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    declare @lowyear int
set @lowyear = 2004
declare @thisyear int
set @thisyear = year(getdate())
while @thisyear >= @lowyear
begin
print @thisyear
set @thisyear = (@thisyear - 1)
end
```

Returns

```
2009
2008
2007
2006
2005
2004
```

When you hit Jan 1, 2010. The same code will return:

```
2010
2009
2008
2007
2006
2005
2004
```

Comment: This only works if there is a date in the table for each year.  If there are no entries for 2006, say, then 2006 will not appear.

Comment: @Jonathan, This code is independent of a table. This code prints "a list of years as a recordset starting with 2004 to current year (in desc order), without writing a stored procedure". While I believe that printing the values was the wrong choice, my solution does the same an returns the result set

Comment: This would work, but I like Lievens answer above as it is one select statement and uses some SQL 2005 stuff I needed to learn :-)

Comment: I liked this solution.  I inserted the years into  declare @TmpYears as table(Year int)

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH n(n) AS
(
    SELECT 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1 FROM n WHERE n < 10
)
SELECT year(DATEADD( YY, -n, GetDate())) 
FROM n ORDER BY n
```

Comment: Best performance from all suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:

The CTE is the best answer but I like @Lieven Keersmaekers answer as it doesn’t rely on recursion/loops or creating additional objects such as functions/date-tables. The key variation is mine simply uses the Top clause with an expression, instead of the top 100 (basically the whole table) I ask for N number of **unordered** rows first. This is quicker, if your base table happens to be quite large.

Tested on SQL Server 2016

```
DECLARE @startYear smallint;
SET @startYear = 2004;

DECLARE @endYear smallint;
SET @endYear = YEAR(GETDATE());

-- Top uses expression to bring in N number of rows. The (@startYear - 1) is to retain the start year
SELECT [Yr]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (@endYear - (@startYear - 1)) 
          COUNT([object_id]) OVER (ORDER BY [object_id] DESC) + (@startYear - 1) AS [Yr] -- Add initial start year to Count
    FROM sys.all_objects
) AS T1
ORDER BY [Yr] DESC
```

The comments above are valid, but Since OP’s requirements is literally a small set of values from 2004, the sys.all_objects will suffice, as SQL Server install comes with a ton of system objects.

Hope that's a different take.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers  submitted a variation of yours. it's an old post but I like to live under the "Old but gold" Philosophy, as I can learn a lot from it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a dates table, then just select your range from it. It can also come in useful when you need to select a date range with X data attached and not have any missed days.

Comment: How do you propose keeping this dates table up-to-date?  Is your application going to crash on January 1 several years down the road because someone forgot to populate it with next year's dates?

Comment: Having a date dimension table accessible within your database is standard and extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @max int
set @max = DATEPART(year, getdate())

CREATE TABLE #temp (val int)

while @max >= 2004
  BEGIN
    insert #temp(val) values(@max)
    set @max = @max - 1
  END

SELECT * from #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple query, check this

```
(SELECT REPLACE((TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY')-Rownum)+1,' ',NULL) yr FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL < 32) year
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive CTE with no variables is a simpler way to go...

```
WITH Years AS (
    SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) AS Year
    UNION ALL
    Select Year - 1 FROM Years
    WHERE Year > 2004
)
SELECT Year FROM Years
ORDER BY Year DESC
```