# Get all years between 2 provided dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I have two years e.g:

```
YEAR(@STARTDATE) -- 2011
YEAR(@ENDDATE)   -- 2015
```

How can I create a temp table called `#YEARRANGE` that will contain all the years between the two provided, included the `@STARTDATE` and `@ENDDATE`. In other words, it'll look like so:

```
#YEARRANGE
==========
- 2011
- 2012
- 2013
- 2014
- 2015
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626797/sql-to-return-list-of-years-since-a-specific-year

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
DECLARE 
      @start DATE = '20120201'
    , @end DATE = '20150405'

;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT YEAR(@start) AS [Year]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT yl.[Year]+ 1 as [Year]
    FROM cte  yl
    WHERE yl.[year] + 1 <= Year(@end)
)
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(4), [Year], 120) 
FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #YEARRANGE
(
    Years INT
)

DECLARE @STARTDATE DATE,
        @ENDDATE DATE;
SET @STARTDATE = '20110101';
SET @ENDDATE = '20150101';

WITH GetYears 
AS
(
    SELECT YEAR(@STARTDATE) AS Years
    UNION ALL
    SELECT yl.Years+ 1 as Years
    FROM GetYears yl
    WHERE yl.Years + 1 <= YEAR(@ENDDATE)
)
INSERT INTO #YEARRANGE
SELECT Years FROM GetYears ORDER BY Years;

SELECT * FROM #YEARRANGE

DROP TABLE #YEARRANGE
```

OUTPUT:

```
year
2011
2012
2013
2014
2015
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATE, @ENDDATE DATE

SET @STARTDATE = '2011-01-10'
SET @ENDDATE = '2015-06-16'

CREATE TABLE #YEARRANGE([YEAR] INT)

;WITH C AS (
        SELECT  DATEPART(YEAR, @STARTDATE) AS yr
        UNION ALL
        SELECT yr + 1
        FROM C
        WHERE yr < DATEPART(YEAR, @ENDDATE)
        )
INSERT INTO #YEARRANGE
SELECT yr
FROM C
ORDER BY yr

SELECT * FROM #YEARRANGE
```

Output

```
YEAR
------------
2011
2012
2013
2014
2015
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE INT  = 2011

DECLARE @ENDDATE INT = 2015

CREATE TABLE #YEARRANGE([YEAR] INT)

WHILE @STARTDATE <= @ENDDATE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #YEARRANGE
    VALUES(@STARTDATE)

    SET @STARTDATE = @STARTDATE + 1
END


SELECT * FROM #YEARRANGE

DROP TABLE #YEARRANGE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using a Tally Table:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE = '20110101'
DECLARE @endDate DATE = '20150101'

;WITH E1(N) AS(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
)
,E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b)
,E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b)
,Tally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF(YEAR, @startDate, @endDate) + 1) 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM E4
)
SELECT
    YEAR(@startDate) + (N-1)
FROM Tally
WHERE
    YEAR(@startDate) + (N-1) <= YEAR(@endDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with recursive cte and then directly create temp table using `select into` statement, which automatically creates the temp table without explicit creating the last:

```
DECLARE @sd INT = 2011, @ed INT = 2015

;WITH cte AS(SELECT @sd AS y
             UNION ALL
             SELECT y + 1 FROM cte WHERE y < @ed)
SELECT * INTO #YEARRANGE FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Welp, someone may have beat me to this variation.

```
Declare @StartYear int = 2011
    , @EndYear int = 2015
Declare @YearDiff int = @EndYear - @StartYear 
    , @i int =0 --Counter

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#YEARRANGE') is not null
    drop table #YEARRANGE;
Create Table #YEARRANGE (YearRange int)

-- I hate loops in SQL.
while @i <= @YearDiff
begin
    INSERT INTO #YEARRANGE
    select @i + @StartYear
    set @i +=1;
end

/*  Tada    */
Select * 
from #YEARRANGE
```