# SQL Editing Year

Tags: sql, sql-server

The query works but only give years 1985 values. How do I add unlimited amount of years (1985-2014)

```
use baseball; 

SELECT CAST(tf.franchname AS CHAR(20)), s.yearID, s.lgid, AVG(s.salary) 
FROM salaries s, teams t, teamsfranchises tf 
WHERE s.teamID = t.teamID AND
t.franchID = tf.franchID AND 
s.yearID = 1985 AND
(s.lgid='AL' OR s.lgid='NL') GROUP BY tf.franchname,  s.yearID, s.lgid order BY
s.yearID;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select cast(tf.franchname as char(20)), s.yearID, s.lgid, avg(s.salary) 
from salaries s, teams t, teamsfranchises tf 
where s.teamID = t.teamID and
t.franchID = tf.franchID and 
(s.yearID between 1985  and 2014 )and 
(s.lgid='AL' OR s.lgid='NL') 
group by tf.franchname,  s.yearID, s.lgid 
order by s.yearID;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just use [BETWEEN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx).

Your where clause should then look like

```
(s.yearID BETWEEN 1985 AND 2014) and
```

Alternatively you could use the `<` and `>` operators:

```
(s.yearID >= 1984 and <= 2014)
```

If, for any reason you don't have a continous range of years (You only want 5 years). `IN` could also be an option:

```
s.yearID IN (1984, 1991, 1996, 2001, 2006)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query has a condition filtering on the year `and s.yearID = 1985`, you may want to change it using the keyword `BETWEEN` or removing it altogether depending of your need.

Answer (score 0):

This is another view, when there is no data and still you want to get the year with zero count. Just check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626797/sql-to-return-list-of-years-since-a-specific-year)

In this you can create a temporary table which return the list of your years ie  1985 to 2015 , then just join with left outer join and see the magic.

I just get yourquery, you can replace with the accepted answer query too.

```
Declare @Startyear int = 1985
--1st approach to get continues year
;with yearlist as 
(
    select 1985 as year
    union all
    select yl.year + 1 as year
    from yearlist yl
    where yl.year + 1 <= YEAR(GetDate())
)

select year from yearlist order by year desc;

--2nd approach to get continues year
;WITH n(n) AS
(
    SELECT 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1 FROM n WHERE n <  (year(getdate()) -@Startyear)
)
SELECT year(DATEADD( YY, -n, GetDate())) 
FROM n ORDER BY n


--take anyone approach and then join with your query 
;with yearlist as 
(
    select 1985 as year
    union all
    select yl.year + 1 as year
    from yearlist yl
    where yl.year + 1 <= YEAR(GetDate())
)

select year from yearlist 
left join
(
    SELECT CAST(tf.franchname AS CHAR(20)), s.yearID, s.lgid, AVG(s.salary) 
    FROM salaries s, teams t, teamsfranchises tf 
    WHERE s.teamID = t.teamID AND
    t.franchID = tf.franchID AND 
    s.yearID = 1985 AND
    (s.lgid='AL' OR s.lgid='NL') GROUP BY tf.franchname,  s.yearID, s.lgid order BY
    s.yearID
) yourtable on yourtable.yearID  = yearlist.year
order by year desc;
```