# How to select a list of years x number of years from this year

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to construct a select statement in psql with a list of years that is (x) number of years prior to "this year".

Modifications of the answer provided in [SQL to return list of years since a specific year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626797/sql-to-return-list-of-years-since-a-specific-year) work for sql, but not for postgres.

Have tried tinkering with generate_series, but unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

Use -1 step. Example x = 15

```
select * 
from 
    generate_series(
        extract(year from current_date)::int, 
        extract(year from current_date)::int - 15, 
        -1
    )
```

Another approach:

```
select 
    extract(year from x.y)
from 
    generate_series(
        current_timestamp, 
        current_timestamp - interval '1 year' * 15, 
        interval '-1 year'
    ) as x(y)
```

Live test: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/shVQnibndNh45uCZxt4jgs/3

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/shVQnibndNh45uCZxt4jgs/0

Comment: Thank you! Worked. Took option one and wrapped it in a "With" clause in order to get the final result as a char, which seems to work.

with yearlist as (select * from generate_series(
        extract(year from current_date)::int, 
        extract(year from current_date)::int - 70, 
        -1
    ) as Years)
    
select cast(Years as CHAR(4))
from yearlist

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter: you can also use the numeric variant of the [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) function and cast the return value of the [`EXTRACT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function directly, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE + ('1y'::interval * x))::text AS year
FROM
    generate_series(-7, -1) AS x
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to what the "years" as dates, you can do:

```
select *
from generate_series(date_trunc('year', now()) - interval '15 year',
                     date_trunc('year', now()),
                     interval '1 year'
                    )
```

(That is how I would normally want a list of years.)

More importantly, you can easily adapt the SQL Server code to Postgres:

```
with recursive yearlist as  (
      select extract(year from now()) as year, 1 as lev
      union all
      select yl.year - 1 as year, lev + 1
      from yearlist yl
      where lev < 15
  )
select year
from yearlist
order by year desc;
```

I recommend `generate_series()` instead, but I want to demonstrate that Postgres also supports recursive CTEs.